# weebly : A record Mapping

Tags: apache, dns, url-routing

I want to know how is this done. I make a site at weebly, ( it's a sitebuilder).

I get a site `xxx.weebly.com`

If I want my custom domain name, I set A record of custom domain name to point to server : `199.34.228.100`

Question is, **how** that default application(on `199.34.228.100`) works which takes my domain name and show the content of the site to me?

Comment: Not that I completely understand what you are asking - is the IP you posted the dedicated IP of your "weebly" subdomain? If so and if you've done this recently, have you considered [ttl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live)? I think this question might be better directed at your sitebuilder's support staff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your custom domain name is 'mysite.com'. At weebly, you set the A record to 199.34.228.100 which is like saying 'when someone wants to access 'mysite.com' I want them to be sent to 199.34.228.100.

This information is given to all the dns servers around the internet over the next few hours but can sometimes take longer. Afterwards, whenever a request is sent out for 'mysite.com' it will be mapped to 199.34.228.100.

This is weebly.com and when the request arrives, it will come with information saying that the original request was for 'mysite.com'. Weebly then looks in it's records to see who wanted that to happen, see that you made the change and knowing that you have xxx.weebly.com, show that site.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This process is called domain forwarding to external IP address.
The information about redirection is to be set in following order:

#### 1)

first at A record - this information means that all internet traffic at "yourdomain.com" should be forwarded to weebly static IP address (one of several provided by weebly)

#### 2)

make changes in weebly panel to configure your web page - entering "yourdomain.com" as main url

http://kb.weebly.com/domain-registrar.html

best,
Peter